# what if steps_per_epoch does not fit into numbers of samples?

Tags: keras, generator

using Keras `fit_generator`, steps_per_epoch should be equivalent to the total number available of samples divided by the `batch_size`.

But how would the generator or the `fit_generator` react if I choose a `batch_size` that does not fit n times into the samples? Does it yield samples until it cannot fill a whole `batch_size` anymore or does it just use a smaller `batch_size` for the last yield?

Why I ask: I divide my data into train/validation/test of different size (different %) but would use the same batch size for train and validation sets but especially for train and test sets. As they are different in size I cannot guarantee that batch size fit into the total amount of samples.

Answer (score 7):

### If it's your generator with `yield`

It's you who create the generator, so the behavior is defined by you.

If `steps_per_epoch` is greater than the expected batches, fit will not see anything, it will simply keep requesting batches until it reaches the number of steps.

The only thing is: you must assure your generator is infinite.

Do this with `while True:` at the beginning, for instance.

### If it's a generator from `ImageDataGenerator`.

If the generator is from an `ImageDataGenerator`, it's actually a `keras.utils.Sequence` and it has the length property: `len(generatorInstance)`.

Then you can check yourself what happens:

```
remainingSamples = total_samples % batch_size #confirm that this is gerater than 0
wholeBatches = total_samples // batch_size
totalBatches = wholeBatches + 1

if len(generator) == wholeBatches:
    print("missing the last batch")    
elif len(generator) == totalBatches:
    print("last batch included")
else:
    print('weird behavior')
```

And check the size of the last batch:

```
lastBatch = generator[len(generator)-1]

if lastBatch.shape[0] == remainingSamples:
    print('last batch contains the remaining samples')
else:
    print('last batch is different')
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Great to see you again,
I use a classic "while n<len(Data) in the generator. I was jsut wondering as the Keras documentation says: "Total number of steps .. to yield from generator....
So my  generator would not "return"any data as n>len(Data). I was just wondering what the fit_generator function does with no returned values.

Comment: See improved answer.

Comment: A more complete answer it is :) However, to cover cases when `total_samples` *is* a multiple of `batch_size`, I would write `totalBatches = wholeBatches + (remainingSamples != 0)` (or simply `totalBatches = np.ceil(total_samples / batch_size)`, and change a bit the conditions below accordingly...?

Comment: Indeed, I was only "checking" a `Sequence` generator to see what it does (since you don't create it).

Answer (score 2):

If you assign `N` to the parameter `steps_per_epoch` of `fit_generator()`, Keras will basically call your generator `N` times before considering one epoch done. It's up to your generator to yield all your samples in `N` batches.

Note that since for most models it is fine to have different batch sizes each iteration, you could fix `steps_per_epoch = ceil(dataset_size / batch_size)` and let your generator output a smaller batch for the last samples.

Answer (score 0):

i had facing the same logical error
solved it with defining `steps_per_epochs`

```
BS = 32
steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS
history = model.fit(train_batches,
                epochs=initial_epochs,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                validation_data=validation_batches)
```