# What if the validation step does not fit into numbers of samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

It's a bit annoying that `tf.keras` generator still faces this issue, unlike `pytorch`. There are many discussions regarding this, however, still stuck with it. Already visit:

- [Meaning of validation_steps in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943675/meaning-of-validation-steps-in-keras-sequential-fit-generator-parameter-list/45944225)
- [steps_per_epoch does not fit into numbers of samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643963/what-if-steps-per-epoch-does-not-fit-into-numbers-of-samples)

#### Problem

I have a data set consist of around **21397**. I wrote a custom data loader which returns the total number of samples as follows:

```py
class NGenerator(Sequence):
  ...

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(float(len(self.data)) / float(self.batch_size)))
  ...
```

From the data, I've made 5 fold subset of it. Each fold contains as follows:

```
Fold   Amount
1.0    4280
0.0    4280
2.0    4279
3.0    4279
4.0    4279
```

For each fold, I've set `step_per_epoch` and `validation_per_epoch` as follows:

```py
# here, train_labels is the df of the subset based on fold
steps_per_epoch  = np.ceil(float(len(train_labels)) / float(batch_size)) 
validation_steps = np.ceil(float(len(val_labels)) / float(batch_size))
```

Now, to make an **OOF** score, we predict on the validation set and wanted to store results as follows:

```py
batch_size = 64
oof = np.zeros(len(df))
...
for each_fold, (trn_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(skf...): 
   train_labels = df.iloc[self.trn_idx].reset_index(drop=True) 
   val_labels = df.iloc[self.val_idx].reset_index(drop=True) 
   ....
   train_gen, val_gen = ..., model.fit()

   pred = model.predict(val_gen, steps=validation_steps)
   oof[self.val_idx] = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)  < --------- HERE
```

After training, at indexing time (`oof`), it throws a size mismatch of shape between `4280` and `4288`. So, it looks like, with this `step size` and `batch size`, the model is predicting `8` samples of the next batch. Next, we set `batch_size` equal to `40` which dividable by the total number of the subset (`4280`). Good enough but (of course) faced again size mismatch in **Fold 2** of shape between `4279` and `4280`. One of the simple workarounds is to add `3` samples in fold `2,3,4` -_-

Any general tips to get rid of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not have time to go through all your code however I thought the code below might be useful to you. The variable-length should be set to the number of samples. Then the code determines a `batch size` and `steps per epoch` such that `length = batch_size*steps` per epoch. Variable `b_max` should be set to the **maximum batch size** you will allow based on memory capacity. Note if the `length` is a prime number batch size will end up as `1` and `steps` will end up as `length`.

```py
def get_bs(length, b_max):
   batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and 
   length/n<=b_max],reverse=True)[0]  
   steps=(length/batch_size)
   return batch_size, steps
```

I use this to set `validation steps` so during validation the samples in the validation set are processed exactly once. An example is shown below.

```py
batch_size, steps = get_bs(2048, 90)
print ('batch_size = ', batch_size, '   steps = ', steps)
# result is batch_size =  64    steps =  32.0
```